# can't dereference value initialized iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I was playing around the proposed 2d graphics library for C++, the old implementation that I got from here https://github.com/cristianadam/io2d, I am trying to render an image surface on a display surface which i load into vector of unsigned char using the std::copy algorithms

```
auto loadimg(std::ifstream  &file) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> img_data{};
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(file) , 
    std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(), img_data.begin());
    return img_data;
}
```

I tried `std::move` too.

And the client for the loadimg function goes like this

```
std::ifstream file("packagelevel.png");
img_surf.data(loadimg(file));
```

although the program compiles using visual studio 2017. But I am getting the error at debug "Can't derefence value initialize iterator"
and the exception was thrown at the loadimg return statement.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please format your code properly with proper indention?

Comment: Also, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code attempts to copy data into an empty vector. That won't work. Either use an `insert_iterator` for the target of the copy (that will expand the vector as needed) or pass the data range directly to the vector's constructor.

Answer (score 8):

You're providing an empty `std::vector` as the destination while calling `std::copy()`, hence it'll potentially be too small to fit the source data, and so you get *undefined behavior*. To solve this directly you need to pass a `std::back_inserter` as the 3rd argument to `std::copy()`. That way it will append to the `std::vector` as it copies into it, thus making sure it will have the right size -- as shown in the example [here at the bottom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Having said that, if all you want is copying the file's content into a `std::vector` then this would be a commonly used and widely recommended pattern, employing the 4th overload [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
auto loadimg(std::ifstream &file) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> img_data(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return img_data;
}
```

This is well formed as the 1st argument given to the constructor (being of type [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator)) [satisfies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) [*`LegacyInputIterator`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator). The 2nd argument is a default constructed `std::istreambuf_iterator`, which would conveniently serve as the `end` iterator of this or any such stream.

Answer (score 6):

While calling `copy` algorithm vector `img_data` is empty, and when you are writing data to this vector you are getting seg fault. When you don't know what is the size of input data to be written you should use `back_inserter` to append data to your vector:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(file) , 
std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(), std::back_inserter(img_data));
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert elements into the back of a vector using `std::copy` you need to use `std::back_inserter`. If not using `back_inserter` you need to ensure your vector is large enough before calling `std::copy`.